# Get a value from a CSV Gatling feeder to create a POST request body

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a pretty simple scenario to get a random value from a CSV file that contains only one column with header `id`. Then, I want to paste this value into a body of a POST request. An example of the body of my request looks as follows:
`{ "id" : "123" }`. So, instead of `"123"`, I need to use a value from a CSV file. Here are my feeder and scenario:

```
val csvFeeder = csv("src/test/resources/ID.csv").random

val scn = scenario("Test POST request")
  .feed(csvFeeder)
  .exec(http("Test POST request")
    .post(uri)
    .header("Content-type", "application/json")
    .body(StringBody("{\"id\":\"$id\"}"))
    .check(status is 200, responseTimeInMillis lte 2000)
  )
```

This example is the closest implementation I managed to make so far. But it doesn't work as I expect. I can't paste the value from a feeder into `$id` that is inside a `body()`. Currently, Gatling sends the following body: `{"id":"$id"}`

How can I retrieve a value from a feeder and paste it into a body string request?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The code is right. The issue was in the version of artifact I was using. I used version `3.0.0-RC3` of `gatling-charts-highcharts`, `gatling-core` & `gatling-http` and `gatling-maven-plugin` was `3.0.0`. Now I switched to `2.3.1` for `gatling-*` dependencies and used `2.2.4` for maven plugin. Now it works.